# How to perform link rewriting with a .NET Regex?

Tags: c#, html, regex, replace, url-rewriting

I need to use C# `Regex` to do a link rewrite for html pages and I need to replace the links enclosed with quotes (") with my own ones. Say for example, I need to replace the following

```
"slashdot.org/index.rss"
```

into

```
"MY_OWN_LINK"
```

However, the actual link can be of the form

```
"//slashdot.org/index.rss" or
"/slashdot.org/index.rss"
```

where there can be other values that comes before `"slashdot.org/index.rss"` but after the quote (") which I don't care about.

To summarize, as long as the link ends with `"slashdot.org/index.rss"`, I would want to replace the entire link with `"MY_OWN_LINK"`.

How can I use `Regex.Replace` for the above?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for HTML. It's a seriously bad idea. Also, you haven't been very clear on what your requirements are.

Comment: @Lopper: Unlike JavaScript, the C# programming language does not have regular expression support.

Comment: @John Saunders: Huh? .NET languages have a far better regex support than JavaScript.

Comment: @Tim: No, the .NET languages have _no_ regex support. The .NET _Framework_ does, not the languages. This is as opposed to JavaScript, where the regex support is part of the language itself.

Comment: @John, that may technically be true, but it's splitting hairs. To the best of my knowledge, there's no major C# implementation outside of the .NET platform.

Comment: @Max: no, but there are other .NET languages, all of which use the exact same regex implementation.

Comment: @John, yes, and that does not in any way conflict with my or Tim's statements.

Comment: @Max: only trying to make the distinction (that some folks actually don't seem to get) that the various .NET languages all have access to the .NET Framework, and that this is where they get, for instance, regex support. So that "C# regex" is the same as "VB.NET regex" is the same as "F# regex", etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** updated answer according to comment.

First, you don't have to use a regular expression for this job. Just check whether or not the string ends with `"slashdot.org/index.rss"', and if it is, replace the entire string.

If you're using regular expression, you'd better just test whether or not the string ends with 
`"slashdot.org/index.rss"` and act accordingly, like so:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(str,"slashdot.org/index\.rss$")) {str = new_str;}
```

If you insist of using `Regex.Replace`, go for

```
Regex.Replace(str,"^.*slashdot.org/index\.rss$","MY_OWN_LINK");
```

where the `^` and the `$` stands for line/string begin/end respectively. The first `.*` means "capture the start of the URL, whatever it is". The last dot is perpended with slash, as it usually means "any character".

For additional info, see this [cheat sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) of regular expression in C#.

Comment: What I want is to replace the entire link with "MY_OWN_LINK" so long as it ends with "slashdot.org/index.rss" and not just replace part of it.

Comment: So even better, test if the link EndsWith("slashdot.org/index.rss") and if it is, replace the entire string. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(VS.71).aspx

Comment: BTW, where can I find the msdn page which defines what each of the element found in a regular expression string (like '.', '[]' etc) does?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28hw3sce(VS.80).aspx I googled "regular expression MSDN". This was the third link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Will work with no slash, single and two slashes.

```
    string pattern =  @"[/]{0,2}slashdot\.org[/]{0,2}index\.rss";
    test1 = Regex.Replace(test1, pattern, "MY_OWN_LINK");
```

Comment: What is the pattern for "[Anystring]slashdot.org/index.rss" where [Anystring] is to match strings of any length and can be of any value that comes before "slashdot.org/index.rss"?

Comment: You can do @".*slashdot\.org[/]{0,2}index\.rss" so the .* matches anything. This can be dangerous, so use it carefully. You can optionally stick ^ at the beginning and $ at the end to match a full string like @"^.*slashdot\.org[/]{0,2}index\.rss$"